# new image().src not working in FireFox & IE

Tags: image, firefox, pixel

I tried using new Image().src to fire a img pixel, it works for chrome and safari but it doesnt for firefox.

```
(new Image()).src= pixelURL;
```

is there any workaround to make it work for firefox & IE?

Any other way to fire the img pixel other than through innerHTML or document.write?

Comment: oh yes. typo here. i will edit now thanks alexander :)

Comment: whats a pixel image?

Comment: nope, it works in chrome and safari. Just firefox & IE doesnt work

Comment: @DanielA.White Its for tracking/conversion purpose. using a img tag that calls/request to the URL to register the conversion.

Comment: "A tracking pixel is simply code inserted into a custom or third-party creative that makes a server call and returns a transparent 1x1 image (normally a GIF file)." - https://support.google.com/dfp_premium/answer/1716364?hl=en

Comment: using your gravatar as an example, `(new Image()).src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/ccdb625913746b332717305f61cfa924?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1"` works fine for me in FF